# How to convert an excel fiile to .dat file using OpenXML

Tags: openxml

How can we convert excel file to *.dat file? What xl format I should use while conversion?

Comment: What kind of ".dat" file? Is it seperated bu "|" ?

Answer (score 0):

.dat files are just .txt files delimited with " | ".

Use openXML and just write the data to a text file using a filewriter, saving as .dat